# Media query does not work with pixels defined

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

```
 <div class="col-md-4 saldos">
    <div class="saldo">
        <p>Saldo</p>
        <h1>R$ 713,00</h1>
    </div>
</div>


@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .saldo {
        width: 150px;
    }

}
```

I defined **800px**, but it just works on **530px**. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: i'm sorry, this is my first time using stackoverflow. I'm gonna show you my html, if it helps.

Comment: @media screen and  (max-width: 800px) {  }  is it not working ?

Comment: The style line you have works on devices up til 800px. 530<800, so it works for 530px devices. Change for min-width, then it will be greater that 800px devices

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
   .saldo {
    width: 150px;
}

.saldo h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
}
}
```

Comment: I already try this, but does not work either. thank you anyway!

Comment: hello, @alicesesti I think you mistake through embed file CSS, I have a question for you do you embed the CSS file that contains above code without conditions? TRY to embed code like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css">` not like this `<link rel="stylesheet" media="mediatype and|not|only (expressions)" href="print.css">` and put above code inside **print.css** file

Comment: another suggestion you can use this style `@media screen and (max-width: 530px) and (min-width: 800px), (min-width: 1100px) {`

Comment: if these solutions are not working I can suggest jquery operations fo solve your problem if you want